# You can't specify target table 'inventory' for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql, sql, database

> Can you help me to solve this problem.
> I just want to update the price that does not include the other collection name

```
UPDATE inventory SET price = '450' WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM inventory WHERE collection_name NOT IN ('C1','C2','C3','C4'))
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't allow this construct.  Instead, use a `JOIN`.  Assuming `id` is unique:

```
UPDATE inventory i JOIN
       (SELECT i2.id
        FROM inventory i2
        WHERE i2.collection_name NOT IN ('C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4')
       ) i2
       ON i.id = i2.id
    SET i.price = '450' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The name of the column `id` indicates that this is the primary key of table.
In this case you don't need the subquery:

```
UPDATE inventory 
SET price = '450' 
WHERE collection_name NOT IN ('C1','C2','C3','C4')
```